# Print value passed by render_template in flask on HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, flask

Basically doing migration of a project into flask and i have already written HTMLs.Require to print data on data.html ? Can see data while rendering template in **data** variable. Any leads will be helpful

**service.py**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def data():
data = 'abc'
return render_template( 'data.html', data = data))
```

**data.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% raw %}
<div class="row" ng-show="data">
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-bind-html="page"></div>
</div>
{% endraw %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Contoller.js**

```
 $stateProvider.state( 'data', {
            url: '/data',
            templateUrl: 'templates/data.html',
            controller:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jinja template way to access the 'data' variable.. i..e in double curly braces {{data}}